# read.px C stack usage issue

Tags: r

I am following the tutorial [here](https://typethepipe.com/post/ggplot-to-3d-in-r-with-rayshader/) to practice `rayshader`. However, when I used the code below I get this error:

```
Error: C stack usage  17812428 is too close to the limit
```

See in the tutorial, when you come to the step which is the code posted in the question. I get this error. Sample data is provided in the tutorial.

Code:

```
tbl_census_2018 <- read.px("data/census_2018.px") %>%              # Load & format
  as_tibble()
```

Package `pxR`'s GitHub [page](https://github.com/cjgb/pxR/blob/master/R/read.px.R) has more info about the `read.px` function which I am pasting below if it helps.

How can I fix this?

```
#################################################################
# 
# File:         read.px.R
# Purpose:      reads a PC-Axis file into R
#
# Created:      20110618
# Authors:      fvf, cjgb, opl
#
# Modifications: 
#       20111210, cjgb: in the data string, "-" may represent the value 0
#       20111210, cjgb: fixing the strsplit when the split character is contained in the data part
#       20120329, cjgb: number strings in the DATA part can contain ";" as separators.
#               Although deprecated, cases still lurk.
#               20130228, cjgb: There can be ; inside quoted strings that create chaos
#               20130608   fvf: Ability to read files with keys in data area.
#                               ":"  added to defaut na.string (EuroStat files)
#               20130624:  use str_split (line 91) to read DATA area
#               20130917, cjgb: changes to prevent errors with EOL characteres
#               20131115, cjgb: some files do not have heading (or stub): only one of 
#                               them is really required
#               20131118, cjgb: fixed a bug happening when missing (i.e. "..") was the last value in DATA
#                               fixing it required that the last quote was not eliminated (same for first quote)
#               20141222, fvf:  fixing some bug in relation to read files with KEYS (sparse array)
#               20150211, fvf:  The parameter "encoding" is NULL by default. "encoding" is determined by 
#                               the file itself: if CHARSET="ANSI" then "latin1" else "CP437".
#               20150212. fvf:  I have to delete => 20130917, cjgb:  tmp[2] <- gsub(";.*", "", tmp[2])    
#                               many px-files have a semicolon at the end of line in DATA area:
#                               i.e: read.px('http://www.ine.es/pcaxisdl//t20/e245/p05/a2002/l0/00004001.px')
#               20150216. fvf   minor correction of a bug in the modification: 20150211,fvf
#               20150219. fvf   Solving a bug: a missing "DROP=FALSE" was producing a read error on files with a single key
#################################################################

read.px <- function(filename, encoding = NULL, 
                    na.strings = c('"."', '".."', '"..."', '"...."', '"....."', '"......"', '":"')) {

    ## auxiliary functions ##

    clean.spaces <- function(x){
        gsub("^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$", "", x) # discards heading|trailing whitespace
    }

    get.attributes <- function(x){
        x <- gsub( "([A-Z-]*)\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1;\\2", x ) ## separates label-attribute with ";"
        x <- ldply(strsplit(x, ";"), 
                   function(y) c(y, "value")[1:2])
    }

    break.clean <- function(x) {
        x <- clean.spaces( strsplit(x, split = '\\"')[[1]] )    ## breaks by '"'
        x[! x %in% c("," , "")]                                 ## and drops spurious seps
    }


    ## end: auxiliary functions ##
    
    # modification by  fvf (150211): Determining the character encoding used in the file => encoding
    
    if (is.null(encoding)) {
        charset  <- readLines(filename, 5)   # read the first five lines
        encoding <- ifelse(any(grepl('CHARSET.*ANSI', charset, ignore.case = T)), 
                           "latin1", "CP437")  # comprobado en debian y osx
    }

    a <- scan(filename, what = "character", sep = "\n", quiet = TRUE, fileEncoding = encoding)

    # modification by  fvf: 130608 
    a <- paste(a, collapse = "\n")        # Se mantienen "CR/LF luego se quitaran selectivamente

    tmp <- strsplit( a, "DATA=" )[[1]]
    tmp[1] <- gsub("\n", " ", tmp[1])     # fvf[130608]: elimina CR de la cabecera
    tmp[2] <- gsub(";", "", tmp[2])       # fvf[150212] (la modificacion rev 92 a 94) da multiples problemas en INEBase                                          
                                          # i.e: read.px('http://www.ine.es/pcaxisdl//t20/e245/p05/a2002/l0/00004001.px')
                                          # en muchos ficheros cada linea del area DATA tiene ";" antes del "EOL"
                                          # lo que produce que solo se lea la primera de las lineas de datos
    a <- paste(tmp[1], "DATA=", tmp[2], sep = "")

    ## modification by cjgb, 20130228 concerning line separators within quoted strings
    ## ; is the logical line end in px files
    ## so we should do:
    ## a <- unlist(strsplit(a, ";"))    
    ## but there might be ; inside quoted strings
    ## so we need the following workaround:

    punto.coma <- str_locate_all(a, ";")[[1]][,1]   # where the ";" are
    comillas   <- str_locate_all(a, '"')[[1]][,1]   # where the '"' are

    ## ";" not after an odd number of '"'
    ## these are the proper "cuts"
    cortes     <- Filter( function(x) sum(comillas < x) %% 2 == 0, punto.coma )     
    
    a <- str_sub(a, c(1, cortes + 1), c(cortes - 1, str_length(a)))
    a <- a[!is.na(a)]
    a <- a[a != ""]
    
    ## end of modification by cjgb, 20130228 concerning line separators within quoted strings
    
   
    # change strsplit by str-split. In big px-files:
    #  "Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit"
    a <- do.call(rbind, str_split(a, "=", n = 2))   

    ## fvf.20141222: not chage to factor: ++ stringsAsFactors=F)
    a <- data.frame(cbind(get.attributes(a[, 1]), a[, 2], stringsAsFactors=F))

    colnames(a) <- c("label", "attribute", "value")
  
    ## build a px object: list with px class attribute ##  
    
    a$label     <- make.names(clean.spaces(a$label))
    a$attribute <- make.names(clean.spaces(gsub('\\"', "", a$attribute)))
    
    # need to avoid that quotes are removed in DATA part because of a bug:
    # a case was reported where the data part ended in ".." and the last quote was erased
    # and this affected the scan function below
    a.data                     <- as.character(a[a$label == "DATA", "value"])
    a.value                    <- gsub('^\\"|\\"$', "", a$value)   # removes " at beginning / end
    a.value[a$label == "DATA"] <- a.data
    names(a.value)             <- a$attribute
    
    px <- tapply(a.value, a$label, as.list)    

    ## these metadata keys contain vectors (comma separated)
    ## we need to split them (and clean the mess: extra spaces, etc.)
    px$STUB$value    <- if(!is.null(px$STUB))    make.names(break.clean(px$STUB$value))
    px$HEADING$value <- if(!is.null(px$HEADING)) make.names(break.clean(px$HEADING$value))

    px$VALUES <- lapply(px$VALUES, break.clean)

    # fvf.20141222: if there are not CODES, do not create CODES
    if (!is.null(px$CODES))
       px$CODES <- lapply(px$CODES, break.clean)

    # fvf.20141222: Sustituye ["~~~~" "~~~~~"] por ["~~~~~"\n"~~~~"]  en 
    # campos multilinea con retornos perdidos (simplifica la lectura humana)
 
    px <- lapply(px, function(e){
      if (!is.null(e$value)) 
        e$value <- gsub('"[[:space:]]+"', '"\n"', e$value)          
      e
    })
    
    #### read the data part into a 'melted' dataframe ###
    
    ## there are two cases: files with/without KEYS keyword
    ## which need to be processed independently

    # fvf[130608]: add to to read files with keys in data area 
    
    if ("KEYS" %in% a$label ){
      
      ## read the whole block
      tc <- textConnection(px$DATA$value); on.exit( close(tc) )
      raw <- read.table(tc, sep = ",", colClasses = "factor")
      
      ## extract and process the data part (the numbers)
      data.part <- as.character(raw[, ncol(raw)] )          # numbers (last column of the data.frame)
      data.part <- gsub('"-"', 0, data.part)                # 0's might be encoded as "-"
      data.part <- scan(text = data.part, na.strings = na.strings, quiet = T)
      
      ## extract and process the keys part (it needs to be staked a number of times, 
      ##  as many as there are entries in the data vector in each row in the block)
      keys.part <- raw[, -ncol(raw), drop = FALSE]    
      keys.part <- keys.part[ rep(1:nrow(keys.part), each = length(data.part) / nrow(keys.part) ), , drop = FALSE ]
      colnames(keys.part) <- names(px$KEYS)
      
      ## change CODES (if any) in keys part to VALUES (consistency issue)
      # for (col.name in colnames(keys.part)[unlist(px$KEYS) == "CODES"])
      #  keys.part[[col.name]] <- mapvalues(keys.part[[col.name]], 
      #                                     from = px$CODES[[col.name]], 
      #                                     to   = px$VALUES[[col.name]])
      # fvf.20141222:
      for (col.name in colnames(keys.part)){
        if (px$KEYS[[col.name]] == 'CODES')   {            
          keys.part[[col.name]]  <- factor(keys.part[[col.name]], levels = px$CODES[[col.name]]) 
          levels(keys.part[[col.name]]) <- px$VALUES[[col.name]]  ## all levels a VALUES
        } else  keys.part[[col.name]]  <- factor(keys.part[[col.name]], levels = px$VALUES[[col.name]] )           
      }
      
      
      ## extract and process the variables that are not keys
      no.keys.part <- px$VALUES[setdiff(names(px$VALUES), names(px$KEYS))]                       
      no.keys.part <- expand.grid(rev(no.keys.part))
      
      ## put everything together & cleanup
      px$DATA$value <- data.frame( keys.part, 
                                   no.keys.part, 
                                   value = data.part,
                                   row.names = NULL)
    }  
    else
    {
      tmp <- gsub('"-"', 0, px$DATA$value)        # 0 can be encoded as "-"
      tmp <- gsub("\n", " ", tmp)                 # delete CR/LF of DATA area fvf[130608]

      tc  <- textConnection(tmp); on.exit( close(tc) )
      raw <- scan(tc, na.strings = na.strings, quote = NULL, quiet = TRUE)
      
      names.vals <- c( rev(px$HEADING$value), rev( px$STUB$value ) )
      output.grid <- data.frame(do.call(expand.grid, px$VALUES[names.vals]))
      
      # sanity check: avoids the problem of "reclycling" of values if
      # the ratio of lenghts of variables and values is an exact integer      
      if (nrow(output.grid) != length(raw))
        stop( "The input file is malformed: data and varnames length differ" )
      
      px$DATA$value           <- data.frame(output.grid, raw)
      colnames(px$DATA$value) <- c(names.vals, "value")    

    }
    
    class(px) <- "px"
    px
}
```

Comment: When you run the function line-by-line, which line throws this error? Maybe the `scan` line?

Comment: The one posted in the question.

Comment: Um, is it crashing when you coerce it to tibble? Or just the read.px? We can't debug things without a minimal, reproducible example. What exactly is causing the excessive stack?

Comment: See in the tutorial, when you come to the step which is the code posted in the question. I get this error.

Comment: Sample data is provided in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue should have been fixed with the new code release (version 0.42.6).

Comment: Thank you so, what's the `code` for updating the package via `GitHub`?